# Firebase rejects update with PermissionDenied as expected but still the client listening to the node receives the data sent

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, flutter-web

I am listening to a node in the realtime db, and a MULTIPATH update is sent that should not pass security rules. Should pass the write rules but not the validate rules.

Checking the firebase console nothing gets written as expected. But the client listening to one of the nodes with onChildAdded receives the data sent.

Is it possible that nothing gets committed to the database but still onChildAdded is triggered on the client?

I thought this was not possible but maybe I am missing something about rules validation + multipath updates.

event received printed on the console:

> event: Instance of 'QueryEvent' | event.snapshot: Instance of 'DataSnapshot' | event.snapshot.val: {c: true, m: e3, n: 1} [2021-08-31T18:14:33.230Z] @firebase/database: FirebaseError: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied (PERMISSION_DENIED)

the data sent, I am doing a multipath update this way:

```
Map<String, dynamic> updateToSend = {};

updateToSend["status/c"] = move.c;
updateToSend["status/n"] = move.n;
updateToSend["moves/${move.n}/n"] = move.n;
updateToSend["moves/${move.n}/m"] = move.m;
updateToSend["moves/${move.n}/c"] = move.c;

await fb.database().ref('games/$gameID').update(updateToSend);
```

the listener:

```
final movesRef = fb.database().ref("/games/${gameId}/moves");
final streamMoves = movesRef.onChildAdded;

streamMoves.listen((event) {
  print(
      "event: $event | event.snapshot: ${event.snapshot} | val: ${event.snapshot.val()}");
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client that performs a write operation, listeners for the affected paths fire immediately - before the data is even sent to the server. If the write gets rejected by the server, the SDK will actually fire reconciliation events to ensure the app can be put in the right state again.

So: if you *also* listen to the `onChildRemoved` stream, you will get an event there once the server has rejected the write operation. That allows you to then remove it from the UI again. There is no way to prevent getting the initial local events.

Comment: The event on the local client that performs the write contains an estimate of the time on the server is based on the local time and the offset of the local time to the server (that it measures when it first connects). But the server will never see/use that value, but instead uses the actual server-side timestamp that it then also send to the all clients (including the one that originally wrote the value). The originating client should then update its UI to show the server-side timestamp. The difference between the two events is usually pretty small.

Comment: thanks! yes I am testing it, and it seems like a diff of around 50ms for each move. I guess I will see how to synchronize it, thanks

Comment: Yeah, 50ms sounds within the expect range. If you simply show the value from the events in the local UI, you shouldn't have to do any extra work. In this case that'd means you have to listen to `child_added` (for the local snapshot with the client-side estimated timestamp) and `child_changed` (for the updated snapshot with the server-side confirmed timestamp). If you do this, the user will temporarily see a slightly off timestamp - but that typically isn't an issue.

Comment: great! I will try that right now, thanks!